# Бот для Discord

Tags: javascript

делаю бота для Discord  нужен способ определить начал ли пользователь стрим и сделать проверку на ключевые слова в заголовке стрима и после этого сделать анон в определенный канал, о том, что пользователь начал стрим.
За помощь буду премного благодарен.
Нашел аналогичную тему, но это устаревший способ.
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066564/Любой-способ-определить-начал-ли-пользователь-стрим-discord-js?newreg=7b02d707da9e47c68c6ab64440519348](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066564/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC-discord-js?newreg=7b02d707da9e47c68c6ab64440519348)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что данный код должен сработать:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
    // Отскаем ненужные ивенты
    if (oldState.streaming === newState.streaming) return;
    // Определяем объект канала, для удобности
    let currentChannel = newState.channel;
    // Определяем канал, в который будем отправлять сообщение
    let broadcastChannel = newState.guild.channels.resolve('ID Канала');
    // К сожалению, вохможности спарсить названия стрима нет (допустим, что я играю в танки, и стримлю совершенно другое окно, но при определении названия стрима при помощи Presence.activities нам выдает те самые танки)
    return await broadcastChannel.send(`<@${newState.id}> начал стрим в канале \`${currentChannel.name}\``)
})
```